# Gson save int as String

Tags: java, gson

I load this json:

```
{"users": [
{
  "username": "shlomi",
  "balance": "112"
}]}
```

Im using Gson:

```
userAnalyzer = gsonObject.fromJson(js, UserJsonAnalyzer.class);

 private class UserJsonAnalyzer {
    private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
public class User {
private String username;
private int balance;}
```

When I save the userAnalyzer to the json it saves the balance as int:

```
{"users": [{
  "username": "shlomi",
  "balance": 112}]}
```

There is a easy way to save the balance as string: "balance": "112"

Comment: The balance is saved as "balance": 112, because the balance is a int attribute, you could change the typ to String, but the real questions is, why do you want to save the balance as "112", since you can not load it than as a User object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saving an int because your User class has `balance` as integer:

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private int balance;
}
```

If you set balance as string:

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String balance;
}
```

The balance will be saved and then written as string instead; and you can still get the value as int with a getter that returns you the int value.